# NZEC error in SPOJ using Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to submit this program to SPOJ but it keeps giving me an NZEC. I have tested it in my computer and it returns the corect results. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with it? This is how the input looks like: http://www.spoj.com/problems/SERVS/ and this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import sys


input=sys.stdin.readlines()
w = []

for line in input:
    lst = line.strip().split(' ')
    w.append(int(lst[0]))
z=w[1:]
size = len(z)
M = np.zeros((len(z),len(z)))

for i in range(size-1, -1, -1):
    for j in range(size-1, i-1, -1):
        if i == size-1:
            M[i,j] = z[i]
        else:
            if j > i:
                M[i,j] = M[i+1,j] + [j-i]
            elif j == i:
                M[i,j] = z[i] + M[j+1, (j+1):].min()
cost = int(M[j, j:].min())
print cost
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does SPOJ support numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think SPOJ supports numpy. Submitting just this:

```
import numpy
```

fails with a NZEC (probably an ImportError)

You should also guard against an empty line at the end of the input

```
for line in input:
    lst = line.strip().split(' ')
    if not lst: break
    w.append(int(lst[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

I tried to add the guard, but I still get the same error.

As for numpy, would you know any alternative that I could I could use as a library?

Comment: You were right! The error was caused by numpy. We rewrote the code in such a way that it is not needed, and we don't get this error anymore. However, now we get time limit exceeded, and we wonder if it is because it doesn't put and EOF at the end of the input. Is there some way we could use the input argument to stop reading after having read n lines?